# White screen in lumen when added @error() directive or @csrf

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, microservices, lumen

I'm new to Lumen, so I'd like to know why I'm getting errors when I add the @error() directive to the view or blade template, but when I remove the @error() directive from the view, everything works normally. I've been looking for an answer for more than a week, so I was hoping someone could help.

What I am expecting is to show an error in the HTML form when the validation is incorrect, similar to how Laravel shows the error above the input field.

[image: this is from Laravel development the @error() directive works fine]

**This is all of the HTML code in view**

```
<form action="/reg" method="POST" id="registration-form">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username-register" class=" mb-1"><small>Username</small></label>
    <input name="username" id="username-register" type="text" placeholder="Pick a username" autocomplete="off" class="form-control r "/>
    @error('username')
      <p class="m-0 small alert alert-danger shadow-sm">{{ $message }}</p>  
    @enderror
  </div>
</form>
```

**UserController method**

```
public function register(Request $request){ 
    $incomingFields = $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:30', Rule::unique('users', 'username')], 
        'email' => ['required','email', Rule::unique('users', 'email')], 
        'password' => ['required', 'min:10', 'confirmed']
    ]); 
    
    $incomingFields['password'] = Hash::make('secret'); 

    // store to database 
    Users::create($incomingFields); 

    return 'Successfully registered';
}
```

Comment: lummen support the view, can you show your validations?

Comment: here's my validation on UserController

 public function register(Request $request){
       $incomingFields =  $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:30', Rule::unique('users', 'username')],
            'email' => ['required','email', Rule::unique('users', 'email')],
            'password' => ['required', 'min:10', 'confirmed']
        ]);

        
    
        $incomingFields['password'] = Hash::make('secret');
    

        // store to database
        Users::create($incomingFields);
        return 'Successfully registered';